# Create Symbolic Link on Windows using C++

Tags: winapi, symlink

I would like to create symbolic links to my data from my program in a cross-platform manner. For *nix systems, there is the [symlink](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/Linux/man2/symlink.2.html). For Windows, I found the function [CreateSymbolicLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866(v=vs.85).aspx) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197379/how-do-i-create-a-symlink-in-windows-vista) in SO and I am running it in this way:

```
int test = CreateSymbolicLink(input_fileName.c_str(), ouput_fileName.c_str(), 0);
```

But `test` always returns `0`, which means that the function failed (and the file specified in `output_fileName` is indeed non-existent). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I did run [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) right after the above call:

```
DWORD err = GetLastError();
```

with `err = 1314`. Thanks @David

UPDATE 2:

According to @David's reply, Windows does *not* let non-admins create soft-links. I am keeping the question open if a future iteration of Win API changes this. Then I will update the answer. As of 26/March/2015, @David's answer is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866.aspx):

> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

You don't appear to have called `GetLastError`. You should do so. A likely error code is [`ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385.aspx#ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD) which has value `1314`. You'll get this if the calling process does not have enough rights. You need to be running as an elevated administrator to use this function.

Comment: I am guessing error 1314 is this error? Is there any way to create symbolic links in Windows the same way as symlink, without requiring admin privileges?

Comment: You need to have that privilege. That's the design of the system.

Comment: A non-elevated process can launch a separate elevated process, or an elevated COM object, to create the symbolic link as needed.

Comment: Are hard links and junctions possible without special privs? @scap3y and David? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, but that is internal and even then it fails if the user doesn't have admin privileges.

Comment: @Noitidart You can check using the exact same lines of code I have written with the GetLasError(). Cheers!

Comment: @scap3y: You don't need admin privileges to launch an elevated process, just a UAC prompt asking the user for permission to run the new process.

Comment: @RemyLebeau do users have to be logged in as a user with admin privelages for me to run a COM object with elevated privs?

Comment: @Noitidart the user has to be an admin that supplies consent, or supply credentials of an admin user. All this is documented fully.

Comment: Thanks @David I must have missed that, I used `CreateHardLink` instead and it seems to work just like I was hoping (like it works on Mac and Linux) I couldn't find this about the hard link description in docs but from testing it seems that way can you please verify.

Comment: @Noitidart: a non-elevated process can use the [COM Elevation Moniker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx) to instantiate a COM object with elevated privileges.

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau ! But what if the user is not logged in with a user that has admin privileges?

Comment: @Noitidart: If the logged in user is an admin user, UAC simply prompts for permission to elevate to full permissions, without asking for credentials. If the logged in user is not an admin user, UAC prompts for admin credentials.  Either way, UAC handles the details, transparent to the process that is being run elevated.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau ! I'll go with the hard link think because I was hoping for 0 bother to the user.

Answer (score 3):

use c++17 create_symlin instead https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_symlink
It works fine.

Comment: std::filesystem::create_symlink function.

Comment: Why the late answer to a problem that was solved? Did c++17 change the problem, if so could you detail it?

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin, in an even later comment...: I'm sure you've realized ever since that SO is not a discussion forum of temporary quick fixes, but a comprehensive _living_ knowledge base that's been constantly refined (not just expanded) -- more for the audience of random googling masses than for the one single person asking a question. (Along that line of reasoning it should also be clear now, why I'm adding this reply, even though it's likely no longer relevant to _you_, personally.)

Comment: Precisely.  I am Googling in 2022 and @GuillermoPablo saved me asking whether this was better supported in C++17, especially now that the Windows team seems to have finally woken up and made symlinks at command line not require elevated privilege.

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed the USB stick that was formatted as FAT for my test.  the above code should work if you are using the correct volume format and you are in the Administrator Group.  If you are in Windows 10 you should not need to Adjust Token Privileges, and you do not need UNC for the parameters.