# Unable to compile a deliberate file on cygwin

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin, clang++

The problem occurs when compiling the `vim` plugin `color_coded`, and can be  summarized as follows:

1. With `g++ -std=c++14`, `symlink` can not be found in `unistd.h`.
2. With `clang++ -std=c++14`, `mutex` is not supported on cygwin.

So, how to compile this code on cygwin?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

std::mutex io_mutex;
auto foo(){
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{io_mutex};
   std::cout << &symlink << "\n";
}

int main(){
   std::thread t1{foo}, t2{foo};
   t1.join();
   t2.join();
}
```

The following are the errors.

1. with `gcc 5.4.0` and `g++ -std=c++14`:

   ```
   t.cpp: In function 'auto foo()':
   t.cpp:9:18: error: 'symlink' was not declared in this scope
       std::cout << &symlink << "\n";
   ```
2. With `clang 3.7.1` and `clang++ -std=c++14`:

   ```
   In file included from t.cpp:2:
   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/mutex:699:10: error: thread-local
         storage is not supported for the current target
     extern __thread void* __once_callable;
            ^
   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/mutex:700:10: error: thread-local
         storage is not supported for the current target
     extern __thread void (*__once_call)();
            ^
   2 errors generated.
   ```

Comment: Have you tried CreateSymbolicLink from Windows.h as suggested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197379/how-do-i-create-a-symlink-in-windows-vista ?

Comment: @W.F. Did you suggest to replace `symlink` with other function? Indeed, that may work for this example. However, I am compiling the `color_coded`, it uses several functions from `unistd.h` that have similar problem as `symlink` shown here.

Comment: @W.F. Another very interesting thing, if `-std=c++**` is not used, g++ can find the `symlink` function. So, maybe the `include` path is not correct.